# Photoshop - aligning and resizing the image in a smart objest - jsx script

Tags: photoshop, photoshop-script

Pretty new to photoshop formatting but got here with some help. The only part I can't figure out is how to property align the imported "image1.png" to the center top of the smart layer object and to make its width the 100% of the smart layer.
The code is currently working fine but the imported image is placed to the center center of the smart layer and is of very small dimensions after the export.

Any help would be much appreciated!

```
// Enable double clicking from the Macintosh Finder or the Windows Explorer
#target photoshop

// Set the path to the folder containing your mockup files and image file
var mockupFolderPath = "C:\\Users\\Jure\\mockupfolder\\";
var outputFolderPath = "C:\\Users\\Jure\\outputfolder";
var imageFilePath = "C:\\Users\\Jure\\image1.png";

// Set the number of mockups you have
var numOfMockups = 2;

// Open each mockup, paste the image, and save as PNG
for (var i = 1; i <= numOfMockups; i++) {
  // Open mockup file
  var mockupFile = new File(mockupFolderPath + "mockup" + i + ".psd");
  open(mockupFile);

 // Select image file
  var imageFile = new File(imageFilePath);

  // Find and select the smart object layer
  var smartObjectLayer = getSmartObjectLayer();
  if (smartObjectLayer !== null) {
    activeDocument.activeLayer = smartObjectLayer;

    // Place the image into the smart object
    placeImage(imageFile);

    // Save as PNG
    var savePath = new File(outputFolderPath + "output" + i + ".png");
    saveAsPNG(savePath);

    // Close the file
    activeDocument.close(SaveOptions.DONOTSAVECHANGES);
  }
}

// Function to get the smart object layer in the active document
function getSmartObjectLayer() {
  var layers = activeDocument.layers;
  for (var j = 0; j < layers.length; j++) {
    var layer = layers[j];
    if (layer.kind == LayerKind.SMARTOBJECT) {
      return layer;
    }
  }
  return null;
}

// Function to place the image into the smart object
function placeImage(imageFile) {
  var idplacedLayerReplaceContents = stringIDToTypeID("placedLayerReplaceContents");
  var desc = new ActionDescriptor();
  var idnull = charIDToTypeID("null");
  desc.putPath(idnull, imageFile);
  executeAction(idplacedLayerReplaceContents, desc, DialogModes.NO);
}

// Function to save the document as PNG
function saveAsPNG(savePath) {
  var pngOptions = new PNGSaveOptions();
  activeDocument.saveAs(savePath, pngOptions, true, Extension.LOWERCASE);
}
```